# MySQL triggers: after an update on table1, delete rows from table2?

Tags: mysql, triggers

After an update on table1, I want to delete data in table2. However, to delete data in table2 I need for example, an ID which can be obtained from the update on table1. How can I do this?

table1 : table1_ID PK, column1, column2
table2 : table2_ID PK, table1_ID FK, column 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wabbit, this one should help you:

```
DELIMITER ///

CREATE TRIGGER name_of_the_trigger AFTER UPDATE ON table1
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
            DELETE FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.table1_ID = OLD.table1_ID;
    END;
///

DELIMITER ;
```